# Editing X,Y of point in shapefile using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, editing

Using ArcMap 10.1, I edited the coordinates within a shapefile.

They are long/lat but the point will not move to that new coordinate on the map.

I've tried clicking on the Longitude column in the attribute table and 'calculating geometry' but still nothing occurs.

Comment: Use field calculator expression  arcpy.Point(!PointX!,!PointY!)  on field Shape.

Comment: If are doing many editing for x & y through attribute table then its better to extract the table as xls then adding it again and calculate xy

Answer (score 13):

Start editing that shapefile, double click on said point, right click on point and "move to" and it will give you an option to type in the x and y coordinates for where you want to move the point to. the drop down also gives options to change to DD or meters etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are only changing the attributes and not the actual location of the point. The X and Y columns contain only attribute data and not the actual shape/spatial data of the point.  If you want to move the point, start editing, click on the point, and drag it where you want it to go.

Alternatively you can add new points at a specific X,Y to the shapefile like this : http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36680

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates in the attribute table, changing the coordinates in the fields will not modify the location of you point. 
If it is only one point that you want to move, please use the method described in this article. Make sure that your layer is editable.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/moving-a-vertex-to-a-specific-x-y-location.htm