# How to update spatial point locations in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table

In ArcGIS, is there a way to quickly reflect changes made to XY coordinate values in my table?

In edit mode I can change the values in my X and Y columns but I'm not able to refresh the map. Currently I export the table, make changes in an editor (e.g. Excel) and re-"create a feature class from XY table" using my new source file.

Comment: So you want your points to move when you change the coordinates, is that what you mean?

Comment: What type of table are you using?

Comment: If you are changing your coordinates in the field in ArcMap solely, you are not actually changing the location, only the attribute.  For you to move the point spatially you can either right click on it and edit the vertices and drag the point where you want (you can then calculate the geometry on it for the coordinate) or you can edit the point in excel like you are doing and re-add them from the xy table and they will be represented accurately.

Comment: just an fyi, https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/how-to-update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175831/editing-x-y-of-point-in-shapefile-using-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: In the second link from @ed.hank above FelixIP has left a comment with a potential solution

Comment: @Midavalo i could be wrong but i think that he wants to change the coordinates and have the point move, rather than move the point and get the coordinates,  at least that is how i read it.  OP any feedback??

Comment: @ed.hank I believe that is what Felix's calc does, if I read it right

Comment: @ed.hank: i want the point to move after I edit the table but what Midavalo suggest would also work for me. thank you all.